# System outputs "null" instead of desired string

Tags: java, string

My program is designed to draw 5 cards at random from a pack of cards. However, when I run it, the output is:

> null null null null null

```
public class Poker {
    static int numberOfPlayers;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawComCards();
    }

    static void drawComCards() {
        Card[] comCard = new Card[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < comCard.length; i++)
            comCard[i] = new Card();

        for (int i = 0; i < comCard.length; i++)
            System.out.print(comCard[i].getCard() + "  ");
    }
}

public class Card {
    private String[] rank = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
    private String[] suit = {"clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"};
    private String cardValue;

    void Card() {
        String cardOne = rank[(int) (Math.random() * rank.length)] + " of " + suit[(int) (Math.random() * suit.length)];
        cardValue = cardOne;
    }

    String getCard() {
        return cardValue;
    }
}
```

I haven't thought about how to eliminate drawing the same card more than once yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because of this line:

```
void Card(){..}
```

remove `void`. This code represent method (constructors doesn't describe return type - even with `void`). So compiler added default no-argument constructor which initializes `cardValue` with `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

void Card(){

to

Card(){

It is a constuctor not method

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your "constructor"

```
void Card() {
    String cardOne = rank[(int) (Math.random() * rank.length)] + " of " + suit[(int) (Math.random() * suit.length)];
    cardValue = cardOne;
}
```

Due to the `void` in the declaration it is actually a method which happens to have the same name as a constructor and because there is no constructor, a default constructor is added (this is why `comCard[i] = new Card();` still works). But the default constructor does not initialize `cardValue` so it is `null` when you print it.

Long story short: remove the `void`

Answer (score 0):

i just tested your code, your random is fine. but you dont have constructor.
this is a method not a constructor

```
void Card(){
    String cardOne = rank[(int)(Math.random()*rank.length)] + " of " + suit[(int)(Math.random()*suit.length)];
    cardValue = cardOne;
}
```

a constructor is like bellow

```
public Card(){
    String cardOne = rank[(int)(Math.random()*rank.length)] + " of " + suit[(int)(Math.random()*suit.length)];
    cardValue = cardOne;
}
```

constructor doe snot have return type. so in your code when you call

```
comCard[i] = new Card();
```

its actually calls the default constructor which does nothing. and that is why you get null. your value cardValue does not get initialized in default constructor

Answer (score -2):

I think you could just do rank/suit[rand.nextInt(rank/suit.length)] to get a random rank or suit